# Сетка на Unity Scene

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Подскажите, как вернуть сетку на охват камеры?

[[image: 1]]

Чтобы было вот так! Сама пропала, не могу исправить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего на последнем скриншоте видна рамка от Canvas.
А рамка от камеры видна только лишь, когда она активна (выделена/выбрана) в окне Hierarchy.

Если первый вариант, то, скорее всего, на Вашей сцене пропал объект с компонентом канвы.